# Audio source does not want to work even though it is "triggered" by collision box

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

I have a weird problem. I want to trigger a audio file with a collision box. The Debug Log confirms that the audio source is triggered, but it would play the audio. What could possibly be the reason here?

[image: DebugLog]

I have attached an audio listener to my camera, and I attached an audio source to an object that is quipped with this code:

```
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "ScriptableCookbook/Actions/PlayAudioAction")]
public class PlayAudioAction : ScriptableAction
{
    [SerializeField] private AudioClip clipToPlay = null;
    private AudioSource audioSource;

    public override void PerformAction(GameObject obj)
    {
        audioSource = obj.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
        audioSource.clip = clipToPlay;
        audioSource.playOnAwake = false;
        audioSource.spatialBlend = 1;
        audioSource.Play();
    }

    public override void StopAction(GameObject gameObject)
    {
        if (audioSource != null)
        {
            audioSource.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

These are the audio settings in the inspector of the object that has a box collider (is trigger) and these sound settings:

[image]

And this is the sound itself:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are too far away!

You enabled `SpatialBlend = 1`

And in the Inspector you can see the falloff curve and the red line is where your audio listener is at => far too far away to really hear anything of the sound

---

You'll have to edit that roll-off in order to allow your audio listener to hear the sounds from further away.

In general: Is there a reason why adding that `AudioSource` component on demand?

Rather already add it on your object right from the beginning, adjust the settings correctly and in your code only do

```
public override void PerformAction(GameObject obj)
{
    audioSource = obj.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    if(audioSource) audioSource.Play();
}

public override void StopAction(GameObject gameObject)
{
    if (audioSource)
    {
        audioSource.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much but even with a directly attached audio source script, the audio is triggered (and maybe also playing?), but I can not hear anything. "On awake", the audio plays and I can listen it, but via script it wouldn't. Any idea?